# Camel HTTPComponent Options vs HTTPEndpoint Options

Tags: apache-camel, camel-http

To use Camel HTTP4 component - in the documentation, there are options for both HTTP component and and HTTPEndpoint. I understand the difference between endpoint and component (component is a factory for endpoints), but here there are options for both HTTP component and HTTPEndpoint.

Please help me in understanding the difference between options for both. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

These options are set at specific places at the route configuration. For example, when you define the route, you set in the `from` section component options in the uri. For example:

```
from("http4://localhost:8080/foo?httpClientConfigurer=myHttpClientConfigurer")
  .process(...)
```

When you want to add some endpoint options, you usually set them in the uri of `to` configuration. For example:

```
from(...)
  .to("http4://www.google.com?bridgeEndpoint=true&throwExceptionOnFailure=false");
```

I hope I answered your question